# How to create humanly readable delta between two times?

Tags: time-date

Given two times (in the format returned by `(current-time)`), does Emacs have a way to convert this to a humanly readable delta?

Examples could include:

- 3 days.
- 2 weeks, 3 days.
- 3 hours, 2 minutes.
- tomorrow *(possible alternative to `1 day`)*
- yesterday *(possible alternative to `-1 day`)*

... etc.

Comment: What does "tomorrow" mean in this context?

Comment: As an alternative to "1 day" it's just an example, "1 day" would also be acceptable.

Comment: That's only if one of the two times you mention in your title is `now` - right?

Comment: Yes, it only makes sense if one time is current (so it could be an option to display relative times).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```el
(defun my-format-time-delta (time1 time2)
  "Return difference between TIME1 & TIME2 as a readable string."
  (format-seconds "%Y %D %H %M %z%S" (float-time (time-subtract time1 time2))))
```

This relies on the function `format-seconds`:

```
format-seconds is a compiled Lisp function in `time-date.el'.

(format-seconds STRING SECONDS)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 23.1.

Use format control STRING to format the number SECONDS.
The valid format specifiers are:
%y is the number of (365-day) years.
%d is the number of days.
%h is the number of hours.
%m is the number of minutes.
%s is the number of seconds.
%z is a non-printing control flag (see below).
%% is a literal "%".

Upper-case specifiers are followed by the unit-name (e.g. "years").
Lower-case specifiers return only the unit.

"%" may be followed by a number specifying a width, with an
optional leading "." for zero-padding.  For example, "%.3Y" will
return something of the form "001 year".

The "%s" spec takes an additional optional parameter,
introduced by the "," character, to say how many decimals to
use.  "%,1s" means "use one decimal".

The "%z" specifier does not print anything.  When it is used, specifiers
must be given in order of decreasing size.  To the left of "%z", nothing
is output until the first non-zero unit is encountered.
```

Sample usage:

```el
(mapconcat (lambda (delta)
             (let* ((now (current-time))
                    (then (time-subtract now delta)))
               (format "%9d => %s" delta (my-format-time-delta now then))))
           '(10 100 10000 100000 100000000)
           "\n")

;;        10 => 10 seconds
;;       100 => 1 minute 40 seconds
;;     10000 => 2 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds
;;    100000 => 1 day 3 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds
;; 100000000 => 3 years 62 days 9 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds
```

For more details, see:

- [`(info "(elisp) Time of Day")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Parsing")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Calculations")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Calculations.html)